# How to use class in anchor tag and img tag

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

```
 <a href="images/xyz.jpg" class="swipebox"><img src="images/abc.jpg" class="img-style row2"></a>.
```

I have to use above code in cakephp3. I have tried by html helper but there is some syntax error with my code.

Here is my code,

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('".$this->Html->image('abc.jpg', ['class' => 'img-style row2'])."', $this->Html->image('xyz.jpg', ['class' => 'swipebox'])); ?>
```

Please help anybody regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use image method into link method then use `'escape' => false`, see example

```
echo $this->Html->link(
              $this->Html->image('img.jpg',['class'=>'img-class','alt'   => 'img',]),
              ['controller'=>'', 'action'=>''],
              ['escape' => false,'class'=>'link-class'] 
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help